# Removing from superview with gestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I create a blurEffectView as such:

```
var blurEffectView: UIVisualEffectView{
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    return blurEffectView
}
```

And then a tapGestureRecognizer to add to the effect view.

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissBlurView))
            self.blurEffectView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
            self.mapView.addSubview(self.blurEffectView)
```

And here is the function to dismiss it:

```
func dismissBlurView(){
    blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

I am obviously missing something here, as dismissBlurView is not called when I tap on the blur view.

Comment: its probably being overriden by mapView gesture recognizer. Try placing the blurView over the mapView but not as a subview of the mapView. As a subview of the parent view.

Comment: That did not work, and I kinda need it as a superview of mapView, because there's another view on top of the blur effect view that is a child of the parent view that should not be blurred.

Comment: just use bringtofront to your  blurview

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

    tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code because it's working for me. I,ve changed block declaration and set the frame size outside of block in viewDidLoad.

```
var blurEffectView: UIVisualEffectView = {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        return blurEffectView
   }()
```

// Set UIVisualEffectView frame in viewDidLoad

```
self.blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds

        self.blurEffectView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissBlurView(gesture:))))
        self.view.addSubview(self.blurEffectView)

func dismissBlurView(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @thewaywewere Thanks for your suggestion, i'll definitely  take care of it.